# Add top and bottom tabs using react native router flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I want to add top and bottom tabs in my application using react native router flux. Now i am able to add either top or bottom tab.

I tried to use tabBarPosition={'top'} and tabBarPosition={'bottom'} for the same scene.

```
<Router>
            <Scene key='root' headerMode={'none'}>
            <Scene key='auth' headerMode={'none'}>
            <Scene key='login' component={LoginForm} title="Please Login" initial />
            </Scene>
            <Scene 
            key='main' 
            headerMode={'screen'} 
            tabs 
            tabBarPosition={'bottom'} 
            tabBarStyle={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}
            >
            <Scene
            onLeft={() => Actions.profile()} 
            leftTitle='Profile'
            onRight={() => Actions.events()} 
            rightTitle='Events' 
            key='home'
            component={Home} 
            title='Home'
            icon={TabIcon}
            initial
            />
            <Scene
            key='profile'
            rightTitle='Message' 
            component={Profile} 
            title='Profile'
            icon={TabIcon}
            />
            <Scene
            key='events'
            rightTitle='Message' 
            component={Events} 
            title='Events'
            icon={TabIcon}
            />
            </Scene>
            </Scene>
        </Router>
''''
```

Comment: You have already said that you have succeeded in the question. So what do you want to ask?

Comment: I said i am only able to add either top or bottom tabs not both.

Comment: what i want is to add top and bottom tabs in a component

Comment: Can you show me the code you set?

Comment: I think you'll need to build another createMaterialTopTabNavigator.